# mySQL Left Join 5 Tables?

Tags: mysql

[image]Thanks in advance for any help. I am working with 5 tables in a mySQL database. The system is such that I have a top level table called "owners" (clients) that have local business (shops). These owners go out and create accounts at websites like yelp (citation_sources) and as such have login credential (citation_login). Once they have an account at a citation source, they add shops to the directory.

I am hoping to create one query that would select ALL of the citation sources, regardless of if an owner has an account or not, and loop through the recordset, showing login for each citation source they have an account with, as well as any shop listings.

My question pertains to doing a left join on 5 tables. I left out most fo the fields but have set up primary and foreign keys Is the sequence of the join important, ie. start with one particular table, ending with another?

I tried this command but it only brings back 33 rows when in fact there are 96 citation_sources.

I think I figured it out. I created a new table called "citation_shop" with a composite primary key - citation - shop. I then ran a query and it got me the results I was after. I ended up putting a condition in the first left join.

SELECT citation_sources.name, citation_shop.shop from citation_sources left join citation_shop on citation_sources.id = citation_shop.citation and citation_shop.shop in (6,7) left join shops on citation_shop.shop = shops.id  group by citation_sources.name, citation_shop.shop limit 100

```
CREATE TABLE `citation_shop` (
  `shop` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `citation` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  `count` smallint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sort` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `citation_shop`
--
ALTER TABLE `citation_shop`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`citation`,`shop`);

select owners.id as owner_id, shops.id as shop_id, citation_sources.name, citation_shop_urls.url, citation_logins.password 
from owners 
inner join shops on owners.id = shops.owner_id 
left join citation_logins on owners.id = citation_logins.owner 
left join citation_sources on citation_logins.c_source = citation_sources.id 
left join citation_shop_urls on citation_sources.id = citation_shop_urls.citation_id 
where owners.id = 3 
group by citation_sources.name
```

Here are my tables in order of what I think is relevlance:

```
CREATE TABLE `owners` (
  `id` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `owner_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `citation_sources` (
  `id` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `citation_shop_urls` (
  `shop` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `citation_id` tinyint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` smallint(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `citation_logins` (
  `c_source` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: The order of `LEFT JOIN` is important. The table on the left is the parent table, the table on the right is the child table. The result will include rows from the parent even if they have no match in the child.

Comment: Except for leaving out `citation_shop_urls` your query looks like it should work. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I added the citaton_shop_urls and I get a result, but not the result I am after. The owner I am using, owner 3, has 2 shops. THere are 96 citation sources. I get a recordset with 33 rows.If am am ultimately after the complete list of citation_sources, would that be the table I start with?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation function like `SUM()` or `MAX()`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `WHERE owners.id = 3`? I thought you wanted all sources, even those without an owner.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the expected result from it?

Comment: If you found a solution you should put it in an answer, not in the question. And format it as code, not as a quotation -- indent it 4 columns with Ctl-k or the `{}` tool.

Answer (score 0):

In a `LEFT JOIN`, the first table is the one where you get all the rows, even if they don't have a match in other tables. So if you want *all* `citation_sources`, even those not associated with any `owner`, then `citation_sources` should be the table on the left of the `LEFT JOIN`.

To filter the owner information only to `id = 3`, put `o.id = 3` in the `ON` clause that joins with `owners`. Then use a `WHERE` clause to remove all the other rows.

```
SELECT o.id as owner_id, s.id as shop_id, cs.name, u.url, cl.password 
FROM citation_sources AS cs
LEFT JOIN citation_shop_urls AS u ON u.citation_id = cs.id
LEFT JOIN citation_logins AS cl ON cs.id = cl.c_source
LEFT JOIN owners AS o ON o.id = cl.owner AND o.id = 3
LEFT JOIN shops AS s ON s.owner_id = o.id
WHERE o.id IS NULL OR o.id = 3
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough for your help with this. I ran your command and it brought back 19K rows. Given a situation where I want one owner, id = 3, that has 2 shops, ids 6 & 7, I would want a recordset of 192 rows, (96 citation sources x 2 shops). When put a conditon such as where owners.id = 3 I get 33 rows.

Comment: You said in the question that you want all sources even if they don't have an owner. So what does owner ID 3 have to do with it?

Comment: You mean you want all sources, and if owner 3 has an account you want the account info?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is this. A client (owner) logs into a back end and clicks on Citation Sources. He see a list of 96 sources, Yelp, CitySearch, Angie's List, etc. Under each source he sees (or does not see) his shop(s) listed.

Comment: Making progress, thank you. I get a recordset with 16k rows. If I could just exclude rows where owner = null it would work

Comment: `WHERE cl.owner IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I asked you earlier to show sample data and results. Why is this so hard?

Comment: I just added a screen shot. Owner 3 has 4 shops. I am getting rows where owner is 3 but the urls are for other owners' shops.

Comment: There's a way to do this with `GROUP BY` and appropriate aggregation of the other columns, but I'm having trouble coming up with it at the moment.

Comment: That is ok Barmar, I really really appreciate your time and patience with helping me. What if I put a condition on the shop id, such as you did with owner id?

Comment: No, that's not the issue. You need to use `GROUP BY` to get one row per source. The tricky part is making sure all the other columns are the ones that go with the shop owner.

Comment: Interestingly enough I added "and cl.owner = 3" into the query and it got me down to only rows with owner id = 3 and shops belonging to owner 3. But I am still left with rows that have urls from cl table belonging to other owners.

Comment: Try adding the `WHERE` clause I just added at the end.

Comment: Thank you but no, that does not work. I may need to resort to just an inefficient code with nested for loops to put out the data. Or go go back to school and learn mySQL...

Comment: It probably involves using a subquery to get the owner-specific info, and left joining that to the sources table. I'm just a little tired tonight and can't figure it all out.

Comment: I am tired as well, again thank you for your time and patience. I really appreciate it. Have a good night.

Comment: 'Why is this so hard' - well, perhaps the incentive is diminished when you answer regardless of whether the information is provided or not.